# Use the value of the second parameter to get the fifth

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments

I got the following code elsewhere on stackoverflow:

```
@echo off

rem throw the first parameter away
shift
set params=%1
:loop
shift
if [%1]==[] goto afterloop
set params=%params% %1
goto loop
:afterloop

@echo %params%

@echo on
```

Result: Running `shifttest 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` yields `2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

---

After further testing, I've discovered I can throw the first two parameters away by doing the following:

```
@echo off

rem throw the first two parameters away
shift
set params=%2
:loop
shift
if [%2]==[] goto afterloop
set params=%params% %2
goto loop
:afterloop

@echo %params%

@echo on
```

Result: Running `shifttest 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` yields `2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

I've also discovered that I can replace the `%2` with `%3` to throw away the first three, and so on...

---

My question:
Is there a way to specify how many parameters to throw away?

Example: Running `shifttest 5 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` yields `6 7 8`, i.e. the first parameter specifies how many parameters to throw away, including the first one.

I was thinking something along the lines of `%(%1)`, but that obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this simple batch-file (*test.bat*), which uses a for loop to `shift` the command-line params `%1` number of times:

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (1,1,%1) do shift
echo %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

I get the following:

```
c:\>test 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

c:\>test 5 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
6 7 8 9
```

You could easily adapt this technique to set `params` to the remaining parameters.  For instance:

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (1,1,%1) do shift
set params=
:loop
if [%1]==[] goto afterloop
if defined params (set params=%params% %1) else (set params=%1)
shift
goto loop
:afterloop
echo %params%
```

Now running it yields this:

```
c:\>test 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

c:\>test 5 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a *direct* way to do that. This is a simple work-around:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%i in (1,1,%1) do shift
:loop
   if [%1] == [] goto afterloop
   set params=%params% %1
   shift
goto loop
:afterloop

echo %params%
```

The construct that you indicated as `%(%1)` would be equivalent to the following construct, if such a construct would be possible!

```
echo The parameter indicated by first one (the fifth): !%1
```

that is, expand %1 to 5 and then, *with a delayed replacement*. expand !5 to the fifth parameter, but this construct does *not* work on Batch fle parameters, just on variables. The usual way to achieve complex managements is first store the parameters in an *array*, and then access the array elements. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set n=0
:loop
   if [%1] == [] goto afterloop
   set /A n+=1
   set param[%n%]=%1
   shift
goto loop
:afterloop

echo The parameter indicated by first one (the fifth): !param[%param[1]%]!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET val=%1 %*
FOR /l %%i IN (1,1,%1) DO CALL SET "val=%%val:* =%%"
FOR /f %%j IN ("%val%") DO SET "val=%%j"
ECHO val=+%val%+

GOTO :EOF
```

will set `val` to the nth parameter when executed with `thisbatch n 2 3 4 5 6 7`

If n>#parameters, returns the last.

Remove the `%1` in `%1 %*` to yield parameters numbered `thisbatch n 1 2 3 4 5 6 7` (ie n=1 produces 1st after n)